# C# how to get an Actions associated object and tell if it still exists

Tags: c#, reflection, delegates, null

I want to get the object associated with an Action delegate and determine whether its null. How would I go about this? and is it possible without reflection?

Comment: What do you mean "associated object"?

Comment: "Associated object" and "tell if it still exists" are two very ambiguous phrases. You should provide a concrete example to get a meaningful answer.

Comment: Sorry, what I meant is the object instance the Action is tied to. For example:

Action action = someInstance.MyAction ();

I think, a prior answer (now removed?) was correct. Does action.Target give me this instance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`Action`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.action(v=vs.110).aspx) is a delegate type and therefore it's base class is [`MulticastDelegate`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.multicastdelegate(v=vs.110).aspx) inherited from [`Delegate`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.delegate(v=vs.110).aspx) which exposes Method and [`Target`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.delegate.target(v=vs.110).aspx) properties. You are probably interested in `Target` as it *"Gets the class instance on which the current delegate invokes the instance method."* It's value is *"The object on which the current delegate invokes the instance method, if the delegate represents an instance method; null if the delegate represents a static method."*

If you cast you `Action` object to `MulticastDelegate` (or `Delegate`) you can verify that like in this code snippet:

```
public class A
{
    public void foo()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("A.foo()");
    }

    public void foo2()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("A.foo2()");
    }

    public static void bar()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("A.bar()");
    }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        A a = new A();
        Action action = a.foo;
        action += a.foo2; 
        MulticastDelegate d = (MulticastDelegate)action;
        Debug.Assert(object.ReferenceEquals(d.Target, a)); // passes
        action();
        action = A.bar;
        d = (MulticastDelegate)action;
        Debug.Assert(object.ReferenceEquals(d.Target, null)); // passes
        action();
    }
}
```

Output:

```
A.foo()
A.foo2()
A.bar()
```

Note that `Target` returns the instance of the last object added to the invocation list:

```
public class B
{
    public void foo()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("B.foo()");
    }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        A a = new A();
        B b = new B();
        Action action = a.foo;
        action += a.foo2;
        action += b.foo;
        MulticastDelegate d = (MulticastDelegate)action;
        Debug.Assert(object.ReferenceEquals(d.Target, b)); // passes
        action();
        action = A.bar;
        d = (MulticastDelegate)action;
        Debug.Assert(object.ReferenceEquals(d.Target, null)); // passes
        action();
    }
}
```

Output:

```
A.foo()
A.foo2()
B.foo()
A.bar()
```